# Extract the title of a PDF file with R

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract the title of a bulk of PDF files that don't have any metadata in them. The titles are always the first text that appears, are always entirely capitalized and are always emboldened. Sometimes thet titles have one line, others two and rarley three lines. I tried to use regular expressions but I always get only a part of the text or all of it. I' working in R.

```
titulo <- sub("^(\\s*)([A-Z\\s]+)\\s+.*", "\\2", text[1])
```

this code only detects the first word of the title but not the rest

Comment: Please add some data that you're trying to use the code on. So you have already extracted the text from the PDF?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.